# Как менять название атрибута в Woocomerce в зависимости от категории?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Все товары выгружаются на сайт с названием атрибута "Толщина" и его значением. Атрибут вывожу в product loop и в саму карточку. Проблема в том, что некоторые товары должны иметь другое название атрибута (не значение), например фасовка, длина, ширина... в зависимости от родительской категории (в химии - фасовка, в ткани - ширина и т.п.), значение не меняется. Есть смешанные категории (типа акция), где все товары должны быть со своим названием атрибута.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать? Долго искал что-то похожее в интернете, но так ничего подходящего не нашел..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос следующим образом. Создал поле через ACF. WP all import выгружает данные в это поле.

Далее через функцию вывожу это поле, проверяя соответствие категории

```
    // ВЫВОД АТРИБУТА - ФАСОВКА

add_filter('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'show_product_attributes_vors_dublen', 9);


function show_product_attributes_vors_dublen()
{
    global $product;
    $cat_id = 1229;
    $cat_ids = $product->get_category_ids();


    $varia = get_field('varia_atribut');

    if ($varia) {
        if (in_array($cat_id, $cat_ids, true)) {
            echo '<br><td><span>Фасовка:</span><tr>&nbsp;' . $varia . '</td></tr></span>';
        }
    }
}

// ВЫВОД АТРИБУТА - ТОЛЩИНА

add_filter('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'show_product_attributes_tolshina', 9);


function show_product_attributes_tolshina()
{
    global $product;
    $cat_id = 1191;
    $cat_ids = $product->get_category_ids();


    $varia = get_field('varia_atribut');

    if ($varia) {
        if (in_array($cat_id, $cat_ids, true)) {
            echo '<br><td><span>Толщина:</span><tr>&nbsp;' . $varia . '</td></tr></span>';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"фасовка, длина, ширина, долгота. толщина" - это все отдельные аттрибуты. они подразумевают другой смысл, другие ед. измерения и тд
В карточке/цикле товара лучше будет обращаться не напрямую а через цикл

Те заменить

```
echo $product->get_attribute('толщина')
```

заменить на что-то вроде

```
foreach( ['фасовка','длина', 'ширина', 'долгота', 'толщина'] as $attr ){
    $attr_value = $product->get_attribute($attr);
    if( empty($attr_value) )
        continue;

    echo $attr . ' ' . $attr_value;
}
```

Comment: Только не долгота, а длина. Вы же не координаты местонахождения прописываете